# Animate a graphic based timer and progress bar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

[image]

Please see the above image, which shows a graphic of a timer, as well as a graphic of a progress bar, that I'd like to animate as I update the values of each. What's the best way to go about animating these as the values get updated? Also, the timer and progress bar are independent of each other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: example tapku]

Have you considered using the Tapku library to do this for you?

However if I was to do it myself I would use core graphics, and have the progress bar listen for progress updates (or timeout/failure) by subscribing to say MyProgressBarController. I couldn't tell if your questions was about the graphics of doing this or the code.

CoreGraphics can definitely do what you want, use some blur and drop shadow to emulate the edge look.

Answer (score 0):

For the progress bar (the one on the bottom), you could use a `CAShapeLayer` with a `CGPath` that represents how much of the bar is filled in. Then use a `CABasicAnimation` to animate the "path" property of the `CAShapeLayer`.

[Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Core Animation Reference Collection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_framework/_index.html)

Im sure there are many other libraries out there that will do this for you also, which you may want to look into.

Another Alternative: Subclass `UIProgressView` with your own look and then just use `[MyProgressView setProgress:100 animated:YES]`